# why do i get "Media disconnected" on my network card?

Tags: networking, windows-10, dhcp

each time My windows 10 Pro restarts it does not get its network address.
instead it shows:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration
   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : epeleg7
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCI GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b1b2:d302:6015:7fcd%26(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.242.241(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 43621xxxx
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-xx-xx-xx-X-xx-xx-C1-00-27-0E-0F-xx-xx
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

NOTE: some of the numbers above have been replaced with x's by me.

At face value it would seem like my network cable is not connected...
HOWEVER:
1) It is connected.
2) I have verified that the cable itself is not faulty using a cable tester device
3) If I go to the machines Device Manager and just delete the devices for:
   "Intel(R) 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection" and "Realtek PCI GBE Family Controller
" and then tell it to "Scan for hardware changes" it finds them again and then they connect just fine.

it seems like it finds also this:

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

```
  Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Home
  Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection
  Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-27-XX-XX-XX-8A
  DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
  Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
  Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4cdc:fdxx:xxxx:xx%16(Preferred)
  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.xxx(Preferred)
  Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : יום שני 09 ספטמבר 2019 12:53:28
  Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : יום שני 09 ספטמבר 2019 13:53:26
  Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.yyy
  DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.yyy
  DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 26844....
  DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-xx-xx-xx-xx-27-xx-0F-xx-8A
  DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.xxx
  NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

The machine is connected directly to the ADLS modem/router (10.0.0.yyy) which is also set up to be the DHCP server and has a static entry that maps Physical Address 00-27-XX-XX-XX-8A to 10.0.0.xxx.

Comment: Your first `ipconfig` output does not show the Intel NIC at all. What’s its state in Device Manager when it’s not working?

Comment: Have you tried just reconnecting the cable instead of removing the devices, and does it work?

Comment: You could try installing the [Intel driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000020905/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html).

Comment: @kicken - yes I have, it has no effect.

Comment: @DanielB That seems to be correct. I am not sure and will try to have a look next time it happens.

Comment: @harrymc - I will do that, I hope it will help.

Comment: @harrymc - I am a bit confused as to which driver should I install - the line for my  "Intel(R) 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection" seems to be "Intel® 82578DC Gigabit Ethernet" which say NO and NO for inbox support and full support. I am not sure what does that mean and if I should actully install this driver or not...

Comment: I don't think the "No" matters much, but if in doubt maybe the [Intel® Driver & Support Assistant](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html) can do the analysis for you.

Comment: Interesting to say that I just had a restart and it restarted working properly...

Answer (score 0):

I describe a solution applied on **Windows 10 Enterprise (Version 1809)** computer that was **part of a Domain**, and the network stopped working with "**Media Disconnected**"

**Cause**: the problem happened after applying (uncarefully) other network troubleshooting steps (such as winsock reset and deletion of winsock/winsock2 registry keys and other resetting activities) to resolve a DNS issue, as well as a hard power off due to a freeze. So it is **unknown** what was the root cause.

**Symptoms**: The first symptom was that logging in the system using a domain account was impossible, the computer hangs forever in the Welcome screen (no errors or timeouts!). After logging with a local account, the "Media Disconnected" problem was realized.

WLAN autoconfig service would not start because it depends on **Windows Connection Manager** (wcmsvc) which was hanging in "Starting" state.

After logging with a local admin account, the following procedures were applied and it did not help, in my special case, but maybe can help for most of the cases.

**Solutions:**

1. delete the network adapters from Device Manager
2. Windows Settings / Network & Internet / Network Reset
3. netsh winsock reset
4. netsh int ip reset reset.
5. netcfg -d
6. restore wcnsvc registry entries and startup (sc config Wcmsvc start= auto) and restart
7. uninstall applications which alter the original stack (wireshark, vmware, docker)
8. Remove the computer from Domain

The particular problem faced was that wcmsvc (like iptables in linux) was hung in "**Starting**" in a computer that was **part of the domain** of my organization, as said, and this means, my local admin lacks privileges over certain network configuration, like windows defender firewall rules.

The **netsh i i r r** command at some point was giving **Access denied**. Resetting the Windows Defender was not allowed to the local admin account, because it was controlled by a **domain group policy**.

Since wcmsvc role is related to the firewall, you can decide to **disconnect the computer from the domain**. To do this you go to **This PC**, **Properties**, **Change Settings** and removed it from the organization's domain.

This may allow the resolution of the network issues after a restart and wcmsvc started successfully. After the computer networking is solved, the computer is reachable and it can be added back to the Domain again by the domain administrator (working remotely maybe).